# Putting "$@" in a local variable in dash

Tags: shell-script, dash

I have a Bash function that does some string manipulation on its arguments as a whole (`"$@"`) by putting it in a local variable, something like this:

```bash
my_func() {
    local args="$@"
    echo "args: <$args>"
}

my_func "$@"
```

When I run this in Bash, `args` contains all of the arguments that were passed:

```
$ bash foo.sh foo bar baz
args: <foo bar baz>
```

However, if I run it in Dash, only the first argument is stored:

```
$ dash test.sh foo bar baz
args: <foo>
```

Reading [the section on `local` in the Ubuntu Wiki's "Dash as /bin/sh" page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#local), it seems that Dash is expanding the `local args="$@"` line like so:

```bash
local args=foo bar baz
```

and therefore only putting "foo" in `args` and declaring `bar` and `baz` as (local?) variables. In fact, if I add `echo "bar: $bar"` to `my_func` and run it with an `=` in the arguments it seems to confirm that I am adding variables:

```bash
$ foo.sh foo bar=baz
args: <foo>
bar: baz
```

All this to say, is there a way to get the Bash-like behaviour (of `$args` containing "foo bar baz") in Dash?

Comment: Use `local IFS=" "; local args="$*"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expansion of `$@` in `local args="$@"` [is *unspecified* by the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02).  The `bash` shell will create a single space-delimited string containing all the positional parameters as the value for the `args` variable, while `dash` will try to execute `local args="$1" "$2" "$3"` (etc.)

The `zsh` and `ksh` shells behave like `bash` (creating a single string out of the positional parameters, although `zsh` would use the first character of `$IFS` for the delimiter) while the `yash` shell behaves like `dash`, at least in their default configurations.

In your case, you should use

```
my_func () {
    local args
    args="$*"

    printf 'args: <%s>\n' "$args"
}
```

or

```
my_func () {
    local args="$*"

    printf 'args: <%s>\n' "$args"
}
```

I'm using `$*` here to make it obvious that I'm constructing a single string from a list of values.  The string will contain the values of the positional parameters, delimited by the first character of `$IFS` (a space by default).

I'm also using `printf` to be sure to get the correct output of the user-supplied values (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)).

Also, your script should use `#!/bin/dash` as the first line rather than `#!/bin/sh` as `local` is an extension to the standard `sh` syntax.

Comment: In which versions of `dash`? `local foo=bar` works in both dash-0.5.8 and the related busybox ash.

Comment: @mosvy I noticed. However, the manual does not mention that it is possible explicitly, and I'm now wondering whether this is a bug related to the expansion of `"$@"`.

Comment: Yep, that works, thank you! Yes, I guess it should be `#!/bin/dash`, but I hadn't put that much thought into it since it's just an example script, similarly for `echo` use.

Comment: The expansion of `"$@"` is unspecified in `foo="$@"`, according to the standard.

Comment: @mosvy Yes, you are correct. Better to use `"$*"` when creating a single string out of the positional parameters.

Comment: It's not true that `zsh` behaves like `bash`: Try `foo(){ local IFS=/; local foo=$@; echo "{$foo}"; }; foo 1 2 3` in `zsh` and `bash`. Basically, `zsh`, `yash` and `dash` work the same, different from `bash` if not tripping on the non/badly implemented `local` feature. They will  treat `foo=$@` exactly like `foo=$*`.

Comment: @mosvy Huh? If your code shows anything, it shows that not any shell treats the expansion as any other shell when modifying `$IFS`. What I meant was that `zsh` and `bash` both creates a single string out of all positional parameters (yes, `zsh` will use `$IFS` and `bash` does not), while the others does the expansion totally differently, leading to a potential error in `dash` and to just seeing `$1` in `yash`.

Comment: I've re-read my comment and my code shows _exactly_ what I said. **All** the shells will join the positional arguments into a single string in `foo=$@`, some of them using the 1st char of `IFS` (_exactly_ as `foo=$*`), and some of them using a space. Not all shells support `local` and some support it badly, an issue that is orthogonal to this.

Comment: @mosvy Your code returns `{1}` for `yash`, showing that it does not create a string out of all positional parameters. Likewise, `dash` emits an error because it ends up executing `local foo=1 2 3` and declaring `2` local makes no sense to it.

Comment: You're mixing up two separate issues **a)** how does `foo=$@` work in different shells and **b)** how well is `local` supported. If you want a testcase for **a**) have it here: `foo(){ IFS=/; foo=$@; echo "$foo"; }; foo 1 2 3`. If you want a testcase for **b**): `foo(){ local foo=$1; echo "$foo"; }; foo "1 2 3"`.

Comment: @mosvy Well, the only thing I've touched upon in the answer is the expansion of `$@`. `local` is not supported in `ksh93`, so one would simply use `typeset` instead. That is not the issue I'm addressing, and that is not the issue cause a problem for this user.